# what is this window on emacs?

Tags: emacs, install.packages

[image]

I saw the window on the screen of many emacs developers. I feel inconvenient to see below prompt or minibuffer. can you tell me the name of package?

I just googling to find answer. However, I couldn't find the name of package.

Comment: This is not a recommendation question: it's a factual question. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like vertico.el.

"Vertico provides a performant and minimalistic vertical completion UI based on the default completion system."

https://github.com/minad/vertico

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the floating minibuffer. It is called a [posframe](https://github.com/tumashu/posframe) from the package of the same name.